# How to remove default UserValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I don't know, how to remove/disable default AspNetCore.Identity.UserValidator. UserManager has 2 UserValidators now: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserValidator and Penize_eShop.MyUserValidator

Thanks for help

[image]

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddUserStore<MyUserStore>()
        .AddUserManager<MyUserManager>()
        .AddRoleManager<MyRoleManager>()
        .AddErrorDescriber<MyErrorDescriber>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddUserValidator<MyUserValidator<MyUser>>()
        ;

    services.AddScoped<SignInManager<MyUser>, MySignInManager>();
    services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<MyUser>, MyPasswordHasher>();

    services.AddMvc();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}
```

Comment: Check this https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/02/01/customize-authentication.aspx?m=1 `services.AddTransient<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserValidator>();`

Comment: Haksu: solved! Thank you very much.

Comment: To replace check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911327/identity-custom-user-validators

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit UserManager and reimplement methods that should behave differently and inject it as the default user manager.
Or you can change UserValidator for the concrete instance of the UserManager as follows:

```
_userManager.UserValidators.Clear();
_userManager.UserValidators.Add(userValidator); // Add your custom validator(s)
```