# Identity - Custom User Validators

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identity

Helloes,

I have a .NetCore MVC APP with [Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity) and using [this](https://elanderson.net/2016/04/asp-net-core-user-options-and-custom-validators/) guide I was able to create custom user validators.

```
public class UserDomainValidator<TUser> : IUserValidator<TUser> 
       where TUser : IdentityUser
{
    private readonly List<string> _allowedDomains = new List<string>
    {
        "elanderson.net",
        "test.com"
    };

    public Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager, 
                                              TUser user)
    {
        if (_allowedDomains.Any(allowed => 
               user.Email.EndsWith(allowed, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(
                 IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError
                 {
                     Code = "InvalidDomain",
                     Description = "Domain is invalid."
                 }));
    }
}
```

and succesfully validate my User creation by adding it to my Identity service in DI

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abccom.";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddUserValidator<UserDomainValidator<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Now, [one of the existing validatiors](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/e2ef51b57c916345a09e1ba1f58f54b58efb723f/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/UserValidator.cs) in Identity states that the username must be unique

```
private async Task ValidateUserName(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user, ICollection<IdentityError> errors)
    {
        var userName = await manager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
        {
            errors.Add(Describer.InvalidUserName(userName));
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(manager.Options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters) &&
            userName.Any(c => !manager.Options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters.Contains(c)))
        {
            errors.Add(Describer.InvalidUserName(userName));
        }
        else
        {
            var owner = await manager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            if (owner != null && 
                !string.Equals(await manager.GetUserIdAsync(owner), await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user)))
            {
                errors.Add(Describer.DuplicateUserName(userName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Since in my app my login is done via Tenant + Username / Tenant + Email, I want to allow duplicated usernames... has anyone done something similar or have any ideas?

I need to remove this validation and I guess to adapt the SignInManager or something so it can sign in the correct user..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of adding a new validator replace the one added in services, and create your own UserValidator.

```
   services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserValidator<User>, CustomUserValidator<User>>());


   public class CustomUserValidator<TUser> : IUserValidator<TUser> where TUser : class
   {

    private readonly List<string> _allowedDomains = new List<string>
    {
        "elanderson.net",
        "test.com"
    };

    public CustomUserValidator(IdentityErrorDescriber errors = null)
    {
        Describer = errors ?? new IdentityErrorDescriber();
    }

    public IdentityErrorDescriber Describer { get; }


    public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
    {
        if (manager == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(manager));
        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        var errors = new List<IdentityError>();
        await ValidateUserName(manager, user, errors);
        if (manager.Options.User.RequireUniqueEmail)
            await ValidateEmail(manager, user, errors);
        return errors.Count > 0 ? IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray()) : IdentityResult.Success;
    }

    private async Task ValidateUserName(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user, ICollection<IdentityError> errors)
    {
        var userName = await manager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
            errors.Add(Describer.InvalidUserName(userName));
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(manager.Options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters) && userName.Any(c => !manager.Options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters.Contains(c)))
        {
            errors.Add(Describer.InvalidUserName(userName));
        }
    }

    private async Task ValidateEmail(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user, List<IdentityError> errors)
    {
        var email = await manager.GetEmailAsync(user);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
            errors.Add(Describer.InvalidEmail(email));
        else if (!new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid(email))
        {
            errors.Add(Describer.InvalidEmail(email));
        }
        else if (_allowedDomains.Any(allowed =>
            email.EndsWith(allowed, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
        {
            errors.Add(new IdentityError
            {
                Code = "InvalidDomain",
                Description = "Domain is invalid."
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var byEmailAsync = await manager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            var flag = byEmailAsync != null;
            if (flag)
            {
                var a = await manager.GetUserIdAsync(byEmailAsync);
                flag = !string.Equals(a, await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
            }
            if (!flag)
                return;
            errors.Add(Describer.DuplicateEmail(email));
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: did not know about services.Replace, this is actually a very good idea and very straightforward! Thanks for the solution and for your time! ;)

Comment: Another option could be to Add your custom validation first before the default validation as suggested here: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/check-for-spammy-email-when-registering-user/
```// IMPORTANT: This line must be registered before the call to AddDefaultIdentity
services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<IdentityUser>, SpammyAddressUserValidator<IdentityUser>>();```

Answer (score 2):

Answer for those who just want to extend existing default user validation, without the risk of breaking something.

You can use the Decorator pattern and instead of copying/changing default UserValidator you can just perform additional validation of the user data. Here is an example:

```
public class UserValidatorDecorator<TUser> : IUserValidator<TUser> where TUser : ApplicationUser
{
    // Default UserValidator
    private readonly UserValidator<TUser> _userValidator;
    // Some class with additional options
    private readonly AdditionalOptions _additionalOptions;
    // You can use default error describer or create your own
    private readonly IdentityErrorDescriber _errorDescriber;

    public UserValidatorDecorator(UserValidator<TUser> userValidator,
                                  AdditionalOptions additionalOptions,
                                  IdentityErrorDescriber errorDescriber)
    {
        _userValidator = userValidator;
        _additionalOptions = additionalOptions;
        _errorDescriber = errorDescriber;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager,
                                                    TUser user)
    {
        // call to default validator
        var identityResult = await _userValidator.ValidateAsync(manager, user);

        // if default validation is already failed you can just return result, otherwise call  
        // your additional validation method
        return identityResult.Succeeded ? 
            AdditionalValidation(user) :
            identityResult;
    }

    public IdentityResult AdditionalUserNameValidation(TUser user)
    {
        // now you can check any value, if you need you can pass to method 
        // UserManager as well
        var someValue = user.SomeValue;

        if (someValue < _additionalOptions.MaximumValue)
        {
            return IdentityResult.Failed(_errorDescriber.SomeError(userName));
        }

        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }
}
```

And then you need to register your decorator, it depends on version of .NET framework, I use such code for .NET Core 3.0:

```
// First register default UserValidator and your options class
services.AddScoped<UserValidator<ApplicationUser>>();
services.AddScoped<AdditionalOptions>();
// Then register Asp Identity and your decorator class by using AddUserValidator method
services.AddIdentity<UserData, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddUserValidator<UserValidatorDecorator<UserData>>();
```